# Comma in "If in addition"

Tags: american-english, commas

Consider the following example sentence:

"If in addition he is happy, we are done."

What is the correct place for the comma(s) for the phrase "If in addition"? I see two possiblities:

- If, in addition, he...
- If in addition, he....

Are both acceptable or just the first one?

Comment: The two-comma version offsets the parenthetical in the usually accepted way, but leads to comma clutter, which is being ditched nowadays. Your original is preferable, with zero offsetting of the parenthetical. Your third variant is non-standard.

Comment: It's helpful, yes.